# Save value inside closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have an object which the property `onProgress`. This property is a function that receives the seconds as parameter, and is called everytime my player changes it's duration. What I want to do is, inside this function, create a property called `oldSeconds`. I wanna `console.log` the `oldSeconds` variable and the `currentSeconds`. In this case, oldSeconds will be always 1 second less than the current seconds.

The problem is that `oldSeconds` is always 0 because the function updates its value everytime it's called. It's possible to achieve this without creating the `oldSeconds` variable outside the function?

Object:

```
var opts = {
  onProgress: function(seconds) {
    var oldSeconds = 0
    return function() {
      console.log('Seconds:', seconds, 'OldSeconds:', oldSeconds)
      oldSeconds = seconds
    }
  }
}
```

Function is called like:

```
onProgress(1) // here oldSeconds should be 0
onProgress(2) // and here oldSeconds should be 1
```

EDIT:

I got it working. So the function should be re-write like this:

```
var opts = {
  onProgress: function() {
    var oldSeconds = 0
    return function(seconds) {
      console.log('seconds:', seconds,'oldSeconds:', oldSeconds)
      oldSeconds = seconds
    }
  }
}

var progress = opts.onProgress()
progress(1)
progress(2)
```

and so on.

The problem is that I don't want to do

```
var progress = onProgress()
```

because the `onProgress` function won't always be a function like that one (it can be a generic function).

So how do 'detect' that the function returns a closure and do what I want?

Comment: Place the `var oldSeconds = 0` beneath the `var opts` and don't make it a nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close, but the parameter is in the wrong place and you're missing the function call for the wrapper:

```
var opts = {
 onProgress: function() {
  var oldSeconds = 0
  return function(seconds) {
   console.log('Seconds:', seconds, 'OldSeconds:', oldSeconds)
   oldSeconds = seconds
  };
 }() // <-- call the wrapper function
}
```

Now the "onProgress" property will be initialized with the result of *calling* that anonymous function. That result will be the actual function to be invoked later as `obj.onProgress()`, so that's where the "seconds" parameter needs to be.

Comment: Yeah! thank you, I understood why the parameter needs to be in the inner function but I missed the () to call the wrapper function. Also there should be an '(' before the wrapper 'function' keyword and a ')' after the last '}';

Comment: @PietroCoelho you don't really need to parenthesize the wrapper function. Parentheses are only necessary when the parser would otherwise be confused. In this context, it won't be, though of course the parentheses don't hurt anything.